# Is there any way to get api input parameters with HttpClient?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, dotnet-httpclient

I'm wondering if there is any way to get api input parameters with HttpClient and help of reflection??
Imagine that I have an API action like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
[Route("api/employees/list")]
public async Task<EmployeeDTO> GetNewToken(int id, string name, decimal salary) {}
```

So what I want is to know what input parameters required for sending a get request? 
The desired output could be:

```
{
   id: int,
   name: string,
   salary: decimal
}
```

Comment: Something like  Swashbuckle? https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @Marco no! the api urls are totally dynamic and may come from different servers with different configs

Comment: I'm not aware of any method, other than listening for network traffic to those endpoints or bruteforcing.

Comment: I am looking for a way to send a request without parameters to api and with help of reflection find the given parameters from response content, I don't know if it's possible at all!

Comment: What do you mean by `from response content`? Do you want to read parameter from json body? Could you share us the flow for your httpclient, requst and controller action?